How to use Gpu for Gstreamer pipeline
Understanding how to use GPU for Gstreamer pipeline.
Hello, So I recently started learning Gstreamer I was wondering if there is a way to use Gpu for processing a video coming from an RTSP connection ? and if there is how it's done
Also I am using Gst 1.20 in a docker container that has CUDNN installed on it so gpus can be used by the container.

Did you take a look at Nvidia DeepStream SDK? Afaik, it does have many gstreamer plugins. Using this SDK, you can create a pipeline like gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location="rtsp://...." ! decodebin ! nvvideoconvert ! fakesink
